# How to render a mobile screen with mobile app running on desktop browser?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ionic-framework, mobile

I want to create a web app such as this?
[image]

I already have a mobile app how do I display my mobile app like this on the large screens?

On large screens, I want a mobile and then mobile app running within it.

[This is the link for the website shown in image](https://mentalmodels.edvo.com/)

I want my Website to work like this, how can I achieve it?

I already have an mobile app made using ionic, what i want is to use that app for large screens like this website has used.

Comment: Just use regular css and html there is nothing special about it it's just a mobile page made in html and css. Is that your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be created by using an Iframe on the Desktop.

So I created an SVG for the borders of the mobile and rendered my app inside the SVG using the Iframe.

Since I am using Iframe so my app takes mobile width as viewport width and is rendered as it should on mobile.

Comment: Hi, I am searching for a template displaying a mobile app inside a website just as you did. Can you share your html-code?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand what you're asking.

To make responsive websites, you should use this:

```
@media (min-width: Xpx) {
```

}

You can define your minimum width here, that indicates the size of browser at which these settings should be applied. If you're using sass, nest this and apply your browser-sized settings there.

I hope that was helpful, but maybe I misunderstood the question and it's more complicated

Comment: Yeah, maybe i didn't clarify myself well, I have a mobile app made using ionic what i want is on larger screen i want to run my mobile app inside the mobile as shown in image, how do i run my app inside the div

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience of this problem but there is a dedicated article here: https://ionicframework.com/blog/tips-tricks-for-ionic-on-desktop/